# Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using a Google Provider in next application , so I have set all the route which is given in the documentation , so now in nav component, I am using the useSession to get the session data , but then it encountered an error which was- please wrap your application in sessionProvider , so after doing that I am getting an error :**Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"**

this is my entry code in the App folder (layout.js)

```
import Nav from '@components/Nav'
import '@styles/globals.css'

export const metadata = {
    title: "prompt",
    description: "this is a page"
}

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

const rootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <html>
        <body>
          <div className='main'>
            <div className='gradient' />

          </div>

          <main className='app'>
            <Nav />
            {children}
          </main>
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because You didn't export the component

```js
export default rootLayout;
```

If it's already exported double check to export the component of `app/page.ts`

Comment: I made the change , but now its showing : Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components

Comment: You have to put `"use client"` at the top of the file. or move all providers to a client component

Comment: like this: https://github.com/A7med3bdulBaset/next-template/blob/main/src/components/providers.tsx then render this component in the layout like https://github.com/A7med3bdulBaset/next-template/blob/main/src/app/layout.tsx

Answer (score 0):

To wrap a context provider around your pages use a custom _app router as described in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).